# File.length() apparently reporting wrong file size

Tags: java, file-io

I am taking a text file in my java code and trying to find out its length. I have stored the file in Notepad and encoding type is ANSI

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("test.txt");
    // creates the file

    double len=file.length();
    System.out.println(len);
}
```

SUPPOSE IN THE test.txt i have taken

hello world.
instead of 12 it is showing 14.. why 2 extra chacter??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because in your file you have "Hello World" PLUS two more characters: 0x13 and 0x10, these mark a "new line" and a "carriage return".

Just to show this, modify your code for it to show your file byte by byte as well and you'll see:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("test.txt");
    // creates the file

    long len=file.length();
    System.out.println(len);


    // byte by byte:
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int read;
    while((read = fileStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        for(int index = 0; index < read; index++) {
            byte ch = buffer[index];
            if(buffer[index] < 0x20) {
                System.out.format(">> char: N/A, hex: %02X%n", ch);
            } else {
                System.out.format(">> char: '%c', hex: %02X%n", (char) ch, ch);
            }
        }
    }
    fileStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but is there any way so that i can remove those?? As those two are creating problems at the later stage...